# shimano M545 left pedal cap unit bolt fallen off during use

Tags: pedals, shimano

I recently (2 months ago) bought my first set of clipless pedals (first pedals I have ever bought, just used default ones before).  Shimano M545.  All was well till this morning when I noticed that the left pedal has lost the bolt on the side that holds it together, (think its called the cap unit bolt).  This cap unit bolt and the washer bits have disappeared, presumably during a ride.  Here is a link to shimano's site that shows the pedal and the cap unit bolt bit:

http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/tech_support/tech_tips.download.-Par50rparsys-0015-downloadFile.html/09)%20PD-M545%20and%20424%20Overhaul.pdf

I took it to my local bike shop and they say they do not have a bolt for it.  Can this sort of thing be found / bought and replaced or do I have to replace the whole pedal?

I bought it from Wiggle and have just contacted them about the issue but wanted the advice from the community about how I can deal with this situation.

Thanks

Comment: That's very odd, since the pedal is just 2 months old. Hopefully Wiggle will send you a bolt, but then I suppose you'll have to explain and prove the bike didn't fall on that side?

Comment: They have emailed back and asked me to sent it all back to them and they will replace it, and refund postage if it is faulty.  Was hoping I could just get it sorted quickly rather than loose my pedals for a while, (make riding somewhat harder :p)

Comment: Be thankfull for their willingness in replacing it :) In the mean time use the old pedal, it's a small price to pay.

Answer (score 2):

Wiggle will do you a refund as well as a replace. There should be no problem with that as M545's are known to fall apart in the way you describe.

Sounds like you are looking for a pedal that works well with cleat and without cleat. I do not think the M545 does either job properly, and, as evidenced, can fall apart. They also do not work with some leading brands of 'SPD' footwear.

I would send them back and upgrade to the plain Time ATAC pedals, also available from Wiggle. These may not work too well with leather soled shoes in the wet, but you can get home from the pub with them and regular trainers without your feet slipping off.

I have updated the clipless pedal page with my own IMHO on Time Atac pedals:

[What should I look for in clipless pedals and shoes?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/827/clipless-pedals-first-time-user-buyer)

Comment: I planned to get the M545, but went for the even cheaper Wellgo WPD982, and after almost 1.000 Km they are holding well! Even so, having an upgrade can be a good idea, but you never know they can also be faulty, it's a matter of luck.

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for the advice.  If I went with those pedals would my shoes be OK (http://www.wiggle.co.uk/mavic-alpine-all-mountain-shoes/) I am very new to clipless and not that confident (as you might be able to tell).  I only normally wear normal shoes for my 2 mile ride to work, rest of the time I am clipped in.

Comment: The Mavic shoes will work with them absolutely fine. The problem with the M545's is that they do have a bump in the middle of them and they just do not work particularly well in either mode. Do read my link to the pedal article + ATAC shoes. I rode in on non-cleat shoes on them today, couple of miles... And you have inspired me to put another question together...

Comment: I had a good read and can see your point.  Bit confused about the atac bit: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/?s=atac+pedal they all seem rather small (I like the base for normal shoes), the couple at the bottom of this page seem OK, but I do not know what they are like: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/?s=time+pedal, or if a sensible choice.  I can't say I notice the bump on my pedal much (have high arches in my feet).  Any thoughts would be greatly appraciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with TWO sets of M-424 pedals.  The right one came clean off within 1 km of installation.  In my case, the pedal looked in tact, but it appeared that the bolt was threaded the wrong way on the right side.  The pedals WERE properly installed by my LBS.  I went back to the LBS and they were stumped.  I wrote a letter to Shimano and got absolutely no response.  This is unacceptable and frankly dangerous.  No more Shimano for me, I ended up with some Crank Bros and couldn't be happier.  The